# Does Kotlin provide any additional security?

Tags: security, kotlin, proguard, obfuscation, bytecode

When we develop an Android app in Java, we have the option to obfuscate the code and built the APK.

Is there any advance feature in Kotlin to do the same?

Comment: You can use the same tools as with Java.

Comment: Since ProGuard/DexGuard/DexProtector work not with sources but with bytecode, they still can be applied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code obfuscation is neither a Java feature nor a Kotlin one.

Since Kotlin is compiled to the same bytecode as Java, you can use the same tools (for example Proguard). Those tools obfuscate the bytecode and not the sources, I think you misunderstood that.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you're running `gradle build` on your Kotlin Android project. Then you'll find following tasks being run:

```
:app:compileReleaseKotlin
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:app:copyReleaseKotlinClasses
:app:compileReleaseSources
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease
:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease
```

As you can see Kotlin sources are compiled first, then the Java sources. This results in only one collection of Java classes which are processed with Proguard; just at the end. There is no differentiation between Java and Kotlin anymore at this step.